# Cannot get count() of PySpark dataframe after filtering

Tags: python, pyspark

I have two pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame objects that are initialized as so (generalized example)

```
df = spark.table(path)
filtered_df = df.filter(df[col1].contains(value))
```

I can run the following code to determine the number of rows in `df`:

```
print(df.count())
```

This is successful.

I can attempt to do the same for `filtered_df`:

```
print(filtered_df.count())
```

However, this is NOT successful. I receive the following error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure [...], most recent failure: [...]
com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file [...]
```

The problem I have with understanding the error is that the filtering done on `df` should result in a smaller dataset. Thus, what could possibly be the problem such that we can apply count() on `df` but not on `filtered_df`? An error while reading the file? Then how was `df` read, which contains the same data as `filtered_df`?

Comment: Is `col1` of `array` type? Also, does `df.show()` work without any problems?

Comment: `col` should be a string. And no, `df.show()` seems to return the same error.

Comment: If `df.show()` is giving you an error, it means there's something wrong with your data itself. `count()` worked probably because it did not have to look into the details of the data. When you scroll to the bottom of the error's stacktrace - is there no more details about what is the error about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

NOTE: The above code works for me on Databricks with following assumption i.e., `value` is a single string or number.
You can try below two routes to filter dataframe element for a specific column.

##### Solution 1:

**Replace this section of your code**:

`filtered_df = df.filter(df[col1].contains(value))`

**with the below code** and it should give you desired count.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
filtered_df = df.filter(col("col1").contains(value))
```

##### Solution 2:

> "You can also use below code to filter:"

```
filtered_df = df.filter(df.col1.isin(value))
```

##### Solution 3:

> You can also use `where` function to filter like `SQL`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

filtered_df = df.where(f.col("col1").contains(value))
```

Comment: Maybe it would be worth to add a paragraph explaining to the OP why his solution does not work. For a person not familiar with pyspark, it's not necessarily obvious that you need to declare a filter operation, rather than pass a column of true/false. The OP might not realize he is doing that, or he might be used to that from things like Pandas.